# Kubernetes, Helm - helm upgrade fails when config is specified - JupyterHub

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub

If I run

```
helm upgrade --cleanup-on-fail \
  $RELEASE jupyterhub/jupyterhub \
  --namespace $NAMESPACE \
  --version=0.9.0 \
  --values config.yaml
```

It fails, with this error: `Error: UPGRADE FAILED: pre-upgrade hooks failed: timed out waiting for the condition`. It just hangs for a bit and ultimately times out. It seems like too small of a change to cause a true timeout. I found this command in the Zero to JupyterHub docs, [where it describes how to apply changes to the configuration file](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jupyterhub/customizing/extending-jupyterhub.html#apply-config-changes).

I've tried several permutations, including leaving out cleanup, leaving out version, etc. The only thing I could get to work was `helm upgrade jhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub`, but I don't think it's producing the desired effect.

For example, when I add a line in my config.yaml to [change the default to Jupyter Lab](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jupyterhub/customizing/user-environment.html#use-jupyterlab-by-default), it doesn't work if I run `helm upgrade jhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub`. I believe I need to specify config.yaml using --values or -f

My overall project is to set up JupyterHub on a cloud Kubernetes environment. I'm using GKE and the online terminal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I specified `tag` incorrectly in config.yaml. I put the digest rather than the actual tag. [Here are the images on DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/tags/?page=1&ordering=last_updated)